# Calculating Precision and Recall from confusion matrix in python

Tags: python, pandas, matrix

I have a confusion matrix for 2 classes with pre-calculated totals in a pandas dataframe format:

```
    Actual_class  Predicted_class_0  Predicted_class_1  Total  
0         0              39                 73           112   
1         1              52                561           613          
2        All             91                634           725
```

I need to calculate precision and recall using a loop as I need a general case solution for more classes.

Precision for class 0 would be 39/91 and for class 1 would be 561/634.
Recall for class 0 would be 39/112 and for class 1 would be 561/613.

So I need to iterate by diagonal and totals to get the following results

```
    Actual_class  Predicted_class_0  Predicted_class_1  Total Precision Recall  
0         0              39                 73           112     43%     35%
1         1              52                561           613     88%     92%     
2        All             91                634           725
```

Totals (All row and Total column) will be removed afterwords, so there is no point to calculate them.

I tried the following code, but it doesn't go by diagonal and loses data for the class 0:

```
cols = [c for c in cross_tab.columns if c.lower()[:4] == 'pred'] 

for c in cols:  
    cross_tab["Precision"] = cross_tab[c]/cross_tab[c].iloc[-1]

for c in cols:  
    cross_tab["Recall"] = cross_tab[c]/cross_tab['Total']
```

I'm novice to pandas matrix operations and really need your help.

I'm sure there is a way to proceed without pre-calculating totals.

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using numpy diagonal:

```
import numpy as np  
cols = [c for c in cross_tab.columns if c.lower()[:4] == 'pred' or c == 'Total'] 

denomPrecision=[]
for c in cols:
    denomPrecision.append(cross_tab[c].iloc[-1])

diag = np.diagonal(cross_tab.values,1)

cross_tab["Precision"] = np.round(diag.astype(float)/denomPrecision*100,1)

cross_tab["Recall"] = np.round(diag.astype(float)/cross_tab.Total*100,1)
```